# How to convert string value to JSONArray in android

Tags: android, json, string

```
String myJSON = "[{"id":1,"latitude":15.9875828,"longitude":77.5377585,"status":"PUNCHED"},{"id":8,"latitude":15.9875828,"longitude":77.5377585,"status":"PUNCHED"},{"id":9,"latitude":15.9875828,"longitude":77.5377585,"status":"PUNCHED"},{"id":7,"latitude":15.9875828,"longitude":77.5377585,"status":"PUNCHED"},{"id":10,"latitude":15.9875828,"longitude":77.5377585,"status":"PUNCHED"}]"
```

i want to convert above string into `JSONArray`

Comment: Search about `GSON serialisation`

Answer (score 2):

Just use JSONArray string constructor:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(myJSON);
```

It will throw JSONException if the argument is null or empty or if the string cannot be parsed as a JSON array.

Comment: done same thing but throwing org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

Comment: it was my mistake, in some conditions myJSON was null or empty that's why am getting JSON exception, its working thanks a lot